# Не открывается PGAdmin, поднятая через Docker Compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin4

Поднимаю Postgres и PGAdmin через следующий docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: admin
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
      PGDATA: /data/postgres
    volumes:
    - postgres:/data/postgres
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    networks:
    - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
      PGADMIN_CONFIG_SERVER_MODE: 'False'
    volumes:
    - pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
    ports:
    - "16543:80"
    networks:
    - postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    
networks:
  postgres:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  postgres:
  pgadmin:
```

Далее перехожу PGAdmin в браузере при помощи десктоп приложения Docker и получаю такую ошибку: `Не удается получить доступ к сайту. Превышено время ожидания ответа от сайта localhost.`

Я так понимаю, что проблема в docker-compose файле, но не знаю, что ещё нужно добавить, чтобы всё корректно работало, ведь делал всё по материалам из статьи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверьте протокол подключения. Должен использоваться http (проброс порта в docker-compose "16543:80"), но google chrome может автоматически переключаться на https. Можно открыть ссылку через другой браузер или воспользоваться для настройки google chrome инструкцией из этого ответа [Google Chrome redirecting localhost to https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https).